# Android Send SMS Permission working on other 23+ devices but not with the OnePlus 5

Tags: android, sms, android-permissions, user-permissions, android-7.0-nougat

I have an application that requests permission to send SMS from the user then sends a formatted SMS in the background. This works on all other 23+ devices except my new OnePlus 5.

Does anyone know what might be going on?

Comment: So it's the permission request that is not working ?

Comment: Hello @Anthony welcome to SO. I'm afraid your question is indeed too vague. Could you include more information as to how your application requests permissions and sends the SMS. Also, which part isn't working and what have you tried to fix it?

Comment: Thanks, I have just come from another class where other users with other phones running 7.0+ are having the same issue. Let me find out how to post a code snippet and I will include that.

Comment: @OmarAflak right I fixed it I am trying to find a way to post snippets to show what the issue was. Thanks all for the help and quick responses!

Comment: Update for anyone who may run across this in the future: My issue was that Android changed their policy giving the user more control over services apps request and it required me to include additional user permissions in the manifest.
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE" />

Answer (score 0):

May be it is happening because of the third party app permission.
One plus uses Oxygen Os and Settings are managed from a custom settings view in Oxygen OS.

You should open the application Settings page instead

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_APPLICATION_DETAILS_SETTINGS);
Uri uri = Uri.fromParts("package", getPackageName(), null);
intent.setData(uri);
startActivity(intent);
```